# How many "read"s does it cost to call get() function when fetching data from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code piece in a function that I call when I need to fetch the user profile data.

```
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future getUserProfile() async {
    try {
      DocumentSnapshot ds =
          await _firestore.collection('users').doc(_auth.currentUser.uid).get();

      return ds;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

With the assumption that user's profile data does not change, does this call cost me 1 read each time I call the `getUserProfile()` function? If yes, how can I change this function so that my function only listens to changes and does not necessarily increase the number of reads in firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `getUserProfile()`, the read counter will increase by one.

Firestore offers an alternative to `get()` for listening to real time changes. It's called `snapshots()`, it returns a `Stream<QuerySnapshot>`. You can attach a listener and every time one of the documents you listen to, changes, it will be added to the stream. Initially all items matching your query (in your case it's only one) will be added to the stream. Your code should be then:

```dart
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getUserProfile() {
    try {
      Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream = _firestore
          .collection('users')
          .doc(_auth.currentUser.uid)
          .snapshots();
      return stream;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Every time a change is added to the stream, the read will be increased by one.

More information can be found at the official [Firestore Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, each function call will cost you 1 read. If the data does not change through out the app you could fetch it at the start of your application and store it by creating a class say `User`, then add data to that `User` object. This method is very useful and would minimize the number of function calls made to fetch data.